# Clipping of HALF plane in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to make a clipping half plane, but I am quite unacquainted with OpenGL.

For now, I use a wrapper to OpenGL's glClipPlane

```
    void gle::setClipPlane(GLenum glp, Vector3 const& dir, Vector3 const& pos)
{
    GLdouble eq[4] = { dir.XX, dir.YY, dir.ZZ, -dir*pos };
    glClipPlane(glp, eq);
}
```

But I would actually like to do a clipping half-plane, e.g. the plane with normal 0 1 0, but only for x>0 and y>0.
Is it possible to do it in a *simple* way ?

Answer (score 0):

`x>0` and `y>0` are conditions that represent two half-spaces. You can set them by `glClipPlane(planeE, equ)`with a different `planeE` for each half-space.

`glClipPlane`is a command for old OpenGL, or new with a compatibility-context profile. For modern OGL, core-context profile, you must implement this clipping inside shaders.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out, that clipping was removed from core profile, because core profile implies the availability of geometry shaders. To implement clipping like fixed function OpenGL did (i.e. introduction of new vertices along the clip planes) a geometry shader must be used. However clipping can also be implemented by discarding fragments in the fragment shader. Depending on the number of clip planes used either method my offer better performance.

Comment: Thanks Ripi2, but that's not what I want to do. I want a single cut, but only on a half plane !